# How is my LISP function an unbound variable?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I define a function in LISP, and it defines correctly. But whenever I try to call it, I get an error saying "The variable FACTORIAL is unbound."

I have tried this on both OS X and Windows 7, on LispWorks and Allegro. The function is -

```
(defun factorial (x)
   (if (= 1 x) 1
       (* x factorial (- 1 x))))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show the code where you call it?

Comment: I get this error from `sbcl` because of accidently using `def` instead of `defun`.

Answer (score 17):

In the third line of your code, you're multiplying `x` times `factorial` times `1-x`.

The first thing to notice is `factorial` isn't a variable: it's a function. As Common-Lisp is a Lisp-2, factorial isn't bound as a variable at all–it's bound as a function.

You need to be calling the `factorial` function on one less than `x`, not `x` less than one.

So:

```
(defun factorial (x)
   (if (= 1 x) 1
       (* x (factorial (- x 1)))))
```

…should do it.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're missing a set of parentheses:

```
(defun factorial (x) 
   (if (= 1 x) 1 
       (* x (factorial (- 1 x)))))
```

Without the `()` around `factorial`, Lisp thinks you're referring to a *variable* instead of a *function*.

Comment: Almost–I almost missed the `(- 1 x)`, too. Though I don't know CL, so I could be totally off!

Comment: @Isaac Hodes: I saw that too but I thought I'd leave it as an exercise for the OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer of @Isaac Hodes, this show you that there is clearly 2 namspace for function and variable in CL. You wouldn't have the same error if you were in scheme. You can read more [here](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Technical-Issues.html).

Comment: It would still be wrong, since you still need the parentheses around the recursive call, but it would be wrong in a more interesting way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind all variables and function calls you intend to use with brackets unless you want them to be symbols. About unbound errors, **Paul Graham** has a good example in his book: [Ansi Common Lisp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133708756)

> One of the most common complaints
>   you'll hear from Lisp is that a symbol
>   has no value or is unbound. Several
>   distinct problems show themselves in
>   this way. Local variables, like those
>   established by let and defun, are
>   valid only within the body of the
>   expression where they are created. So
>   if we try to refer to such a variable
>   outside the let that creates it:

```
> (progn (let ((x 10))
                    (format t "Here x = ~A.~%" x))
                  (format t "But now it's gone...~%") x)
```